# Updating 100s of microservices on parent POM change

Tags: maven, microservices, maven-3, maven-bom

I have 100s of microservices, we are trying to introduce the BOM in our project. 1 issue I can clearly see is, if I update the BOM, we need to make changes to all the microservices. Is there a better way to do this?

Example:

```
grandparent:1.0.0
   `-- parent:1.0.0
          |-- ms1:1.0.0
          |-- 
          `-- ms100:1.0.0
```

Now say if we make change to grandparent, we have to update that version in parent and then in all the microservices. Going and managing these many microservices is maintenance nightmate

Comment: We are currently working on tooling to solve this; consider getting in touch via devopscommunity.org, and my nick (taleodor) - would be happy to discuss what we already have and your use case.

Comment: I think the better way to do this is to question the need to centrally control the dependencies for hundreds of microservices. The main benefit of the microservices architecture is independence between the services.

Comment: @TimMoore I have a formatting plugin, it makes use of formatting_file.xml which contains rules. Now every service needs it. What should I do, go make changes to all the services, and if tomorrow I have to change something to formatting_file.xml, I would have to go make change to every file. Also there should be a single place to manage all the dependencies, like some dependencies are must to ensure pipeline build is success, I don't want a new coder to get stuck trying to figure out what went wrong on pipeline and not locally.

Answer (score -1):

The structure is making them coupled, shouldn't be focus on making independent, even build process.
I think first thing to resolve is to break this interdependency on build process.

If the structure is to just ease the build, there are multiple tools available to automate the build process, for example: jenkins. Jenkins would be simplest solution and popular among build tools.